# Vscode Flask hot-reload

Tags: python, flask

Using VisualStudio code, created a virtual environment with anaconda, and spun up a simple flask app.

Everything is working, but I want to be able to see the changes I make when refreshing the site, versus having to quit and restart the app.

Here is my simple app:

```
'''Application Factory'''

import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

#app.config['DEBUG'] = True #tried this did not work

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True) #also tried app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

Even though I've set `debug=True`, when I go to my terminal and spin it up using "`python -m flask run`"

I get the following message:

```
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Looks like its till in production, even though I've turned on Debug.

Subsequently, I tried

```
export FLASK_ENV=development
```

And get the following error:

```
export : The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path   
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ export FLASK_ENV=development
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (export:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're working on windows, of course `export` will not work. It doesn't exist.

Comment: ...@IgnacioVergaraKausel so whats the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working on windows, you shoulde use set command.

```sh
set FLASK_ENV=development
```

Comment: within the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using windows commands here are two solutions:

1. set up a .env file with `FLASK_ENV=development`. This will save you having to manually set FLASK_ENV globally or every time you open the project up. More info about .env or python dotenv configuration can be found [here](https://itnext.io/start-using-env-for-your-flask-project-and-stop-using-environment-variables-for-development-247dc12468be).
2. transfer over to [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) if you want to use Linux commands. You can either open the current directory mounted (mnt/c/users/.../projectdir) or copy the directory into the actual Linux directory (/home/username/.../projectdir). The latter, copying to Linux, is much preferred in terms of performance and best practices. Given that the tutorial you are following is likely geared towards bash commands, this could save you some trouble if you don't want to keep translating commands to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to debug and reload (hot reload) my Flask project with this launch.json configuration file.

So, press F5 (Debug) and keep the debug mode open, all day. Just change your code and enjoy. This works on Windows 11, without WSL. Notice that this doesn't refresh the page in the browser, it only reloads the python file in the debugpy runtime, but when refreshing the page it load the changes.

.vscode/launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Flask",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "app",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "1",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development"
            },
            "autoReload": {
                "enable": true,
                "pattern": [
                    "**/*.py"
                ]
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        }
    ]
}
```